# What's a good program structure for my REST API in Java/Spring?

Tags: java, spring, rest, api

I've been building an RESTful API in Java/Spring for my website. However, development is chugging along and I now have about 10 routes. This is all in 1 Java file in a single class annotated with the `@RestController` annotation.

I'm starting to think of how I can best organize my API for future use. I expect to maybe have up to 20 routes. I can't imagine this all in 1 class.

**How can I better organize my API?** Should I split my single `@RestController` class into different classes/files according to the type of HTTP verb associated with the request (GET, POST, etc.)?

If I do what I just mentioned, I'd need to annotate all those classes with `@RestController.` **Is there any disadvantage to have  a larger number of classes with the `@RestController` annotation?** Or would this be synonomous with having 1 giant class with a single `@RestController` annotation? (speed, performance, etc.)

Comment: Organize your classes by resource, i.e. feature: one to handle users, one to handle products, etc. The number of controllers doesn't matter in terms of performance. Focus on readability and maintainability.

Answer (score -1):

Identify your context and decide ur api into bounded context  and divideed ur controller,  class should be follow single responsiblity principle and large class  called God class anti pattern.

Annotated @rest controller has no performance impact.

- https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/
- https://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api